# creating dummy CreateShell method While Unit Testing

Tags: unit-testing, c#-4.0, prism-4

I want to Unit Test the view model and for that I am Inheriting Mefbootstraper class so Please suggest the method to override the CreateShell method inside Bootstrapper which returns dummy dependency object.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could tell us the reason of using **MefBootstrapper** when performing **Unit Test** of **ViewModels**. **Dummy CreateShell** method and also **Bootstrapper** would not be needed for simple **ViewModel Unit Test** as they would be independent from one another.

Comment: hi , I am new to view model unit Testing and while Testing one of the view model i need to call its constructor which is taking three parameters viz. regionmanager , composition container and resource manager so for registering all these i need to call run method inside Mefbootstraper and when I am inheriting Mefbootstraper it is telling me provide definition for createshell as well . First of all I dont know whether there is an alternative path to test view model that are based on prism.

Comment: Priya, I've helped you before regarding unit testing your viewmodels. Remember, I commented that your ViewModels should not use the ServiceLocator or Container directly. You agreed with me but said you had no control over the ViewModels. What is the point of testing code that you cannot control its implementation? I would really suggest that the code be modified to take the dependencies as constructor parameters therefore explicitly stating dependencies and making the unit testing straight forward!

Comment: In fact, you should probably tell whomever wrote the code it FAILED the test case because of a missing hidden dependency!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your last comment, you could avoid creating a **Shell** and the entire **Bootstrapper**. So, instead of calling **Bootstrapper's** ***run()*** method, you can create mocks for **RegionManager**, **Comnposition Container** and **ResourceManager** in order to pass them through **ViewModel's** constructor.

This would not be an issue as you would load these mock instances with the minimum information needed for the test.

Furthermore, real **Bootstrapper** would not be needed because its functionalities would not be targeted for testing.

I hope this helps, Regards.

Comment: Thanks a lot I mocked the region manager , composition container , resource manager that is working fine but now on calling constructor inside view model there is a further call to eventaggregator like :private EventAggregator()
        {
            this.eventAggregatorInstance = ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<IEventAggregator>();
        }     and this is generating null reference exception at Current.

Comment: I am glad that you solved it. Regarding the ServiceLocator's exception, the reason would be that it would never got registered on your particular mock container. This job is generally made by Prism on Bootstrapper's run() method, but in this case you would need to set it manually. See my reply on your new other [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20764603). Regards.

Comment: Yeah thanks for the reply but I solved that too and put the answer on that post .